# How to give business logic to the ViewModel Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-viewmodel

I'm working on a training project as a student, but I can't figure out how to transfer my business logic from `NewItemActivity` to the `NewItemViewModel`. It turned out that I have all the logic for validating and creating the ItemModel inside the fragment. It's not good to do this, these are all parts of the business logic that need to be given to the viewModel. How can I transfer business logic to the ViewModel, but at the same time keep the application working correctly? Otherwise I tried and everything broke for me.

NewItemActivity.kt

```
class NewItemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private val viewModel: NewItemViewModel by viewModels(factoryProducer = {
        NewItemViewModel.Factory()
    })

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_item)

        val saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.saveButton)
        val editDate = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editDate)

        val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
        val dateDefault = date.format(calendar.timeInMillis)
        editDate.setText(dateDefault)

        editDate.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePickerDialog()
        }

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkStateDescriptionLayout()

            if (checkStateTitleLayout()) return@setOnClickListener
            if (checkStateDescriptionLayout()) return@setOnClickListener

            val newItem = ItemModel(
                title = editTitle.text.toString(),
                description = editDescription.text.toString(),
                date = Date(),
                isFavorite = false
            )

            viewModel.saveNewItem(newItem)

            Toast.makeText(this, "New item added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }

        textChangedListener()
    }

    private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this@NewItemActivity,
            { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate: String =
                    dayOfMonth.toString() + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year
                editDate?.setText(selectedDate)
            },
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }

    private fun checkStateTitleLayout(): Boolean {
        val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
        val checkTitleLayoutState = titleLayout.editText?.text?.toString()
        val fieldIsRequired = getString(R.string.fieldIsRequired)

        val error: Boolean = checkTitleLayoutState!!.isEmpty()
        if (error) titleLayout.error = fieldIsRequired

        return error
    }

    private fun checkStateDescriptionLayout(): Boolean {
        val descriptionLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editDescriptionLayout)
        val checkDescriptionLayoutState = descriptionLayout.editText?.text?.toString()
        val fieldIsRequired = getString(R.string.fieldIsRequired)

        val error: Boolean = checkDescriptionLayoutState!!.isEmpty()
        if (error) descriptionLayout.error = fieldIsRequired

        return error
    }

    private fun textChangedListener() {
        val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
        val descriptionLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editDescriptionLayout)

        titleLayout.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                titleLayout.error = null
                titleLayout.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        })

        descriptionLayout.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                descriptionLayout.error = null
                descriptionLayout.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

NewItemViewModel.kt

```
class NewItemViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    fun saveNewItem(item: ItemModel) = repository.saveNewItem(item)

    class Factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return NewItemViewModel(MyItemsRepositoryImpl.getInstance()) as T
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The basic answer is that each of your click listeners should do no more than call a single function in the view model. If there's a specific problem you're having doing that, I suggest narrowing down the scope of your question, because otherwise I think you'll have trouble getting any helpful answers.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I understand that I need to separate the logic for validation and display?

Comment: You can use any design strategy you like. You don't need to do it any specific way. Maybe you can be more specific about what exactly you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your main business logic is contained in onCreate, and that's not a big problem when you have little business logic, plus your logic is basically one event (saving the ItemModel object).

If you still want to move more logic to the ViewModel, move the creation of ItemModel to the ViewModel and provide functions to change each parameter of ItemModel there. It should look like this:

```
class NewItemViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private var title = ""
    private var description = ""
    private var date = Date()
    private var isFavorite = false

    fun setTitle(s: String) { title = s }
    fun setDescription(s: String) { description = s }
    fun setDate(d: Date) { date = d }
    fun setIsFavorite(b: Boolean) { isFavorite = b }
    fun saveNewItem() = repository.saveNewItem(Item(title, description, date, isFavorite))

    class Factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return NewItemViewModel(MyItemsRepositoryImpl.getInstance()) as T
        }
    }
}
```

You might think it's more trouble than it's worth, and you will be right. However, there's no harm to preparing for more complicated logic ;)

P.S. I have not tested this code, but it should be basically correct.

Comment: There is no reason to overload your properties with redundant functions.

Comment: I understand that I need to separate the logic for validation and display?

Comment: @Tenfour04 How can you make it more productive?

Comment: @Anderson it's okay to skip ViewModels on activities that have little logic. I have a five-activity application and I skipped it on one activity that was incredibly similar to yours (get two pieces of info for registration to database). Or, you could turn your activity into a fragment to share ViewModels.

Comment: @Anderson Remove all the functions starting with the word `set`. They are absolutely redundant to the properties and are likely to lead to bugs since it leaves two different ways to change each setting.

Comment: @TongJingYen This code is good, but there were errors on it: "Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature."

Comment: Anyway @Tenfour04 you have a point. I should have made the variables private so only the ViewModel can update it.

Comment: @Anderson my bad, I forgot to make the variables private. By making the variables public, the compiler generates setter functions with the same names e.g. "settitle" for "title", hence the clash. Setting the vars to private will also make sure your activity won't be able to control any business logic.

Comment: @TongJingYen I try something anyway, and I try it like that, but the result does not change. Could you show by example how it should be?

Comment: Sorry @Anderson I reposted my comment at the same time, but I wonder what you mean by 'the result does not change'. Making the variables private removed the error in my test.

Comment: No, you should remove the setter functions. Kotlin uses properties instead of getters and setters. It’s a core concept of Kotlin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Look, I've removed the setters, removed the private from the fields, and how can I add data validation to the saveNewItem method?

Comment: @TongJingYen And after changes in NewItemViewModel do you need to change / delete something in NewItemActivity?